# AWS costs to Tableau

Tags: tableau-api, amazon-athena, tableau-desktop, cost-management, aws-cost-explorer

I’m trying to integrate AWS to tableau, having all the cost usage reports to Tableau so that I have better visualization of my costs in tableau, has anyone does this ? I don’t find any useful documentation online.

So far I didn’t find any useful info online, I just created cost usage reports and néed a way to integrate S3 cost reports to Athena and then to Tableau

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I don't think that you can access directly the cost information of your account AWS from Tableau.

I would suggest you get cost data using the [AWS Billing and Cost Management](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-cost-management/latest/APIReference/Welcome.html) APIs and load them into a database or directly in a Tableau extract, from which you can start dashboarding.
On GitHub you can find some examples of APIs usage, not specifically with Tableau but it is probably a good starting point nonetheless.

[AWS Cost Explorer Report Generator](https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-cost-explorer-report)
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could try using Tableau’s web connector API to read from Amazon’s AWS Cost Explorer API — see the documentation https://help.tableau.com/current/api/webdataconnector/en-us/index.html